# After what depth is a subsurface drain (e.g. French drain) no longer practical?

Tags: drainage, french-drain

We currently have a building underway and it's foundation consists of individual concrete footings extending 3m (~10 ft) below ground. It's also worth noting that the structure does not have a basement.

I thought it would be a good idea to install a subsurface drain (e.g. French drain) around the building as a safety/preventative measure. However, it seems to me that maintaining and replenishing a subsurface drain drain at the depth of the footings (3 m / ~10 ft) would be quite impractical and costly. Also, the sump into which it drains would be equally deep and hard to maintain.

What are my options in this scenario?

- Do foundations as deep as mine usually implement subsurface drainage?
- Is a subsurface drain even worth having in my scenario? (Recall there is no basement.)
- Should I split the difference and install the drain at a shallower depth above the footings?

Comment: is there a water problem? if there is a french drain would help drain away from the building. I have never installed one over 6' deep and that one was to keep a slope so the water would drain to a  creek several hundred feet away

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a pier foundation. Piers should be deep enough that they are hitting undisturbed, solid soil or bedrock. As such, there's likely little reason to have a french drain in that situation as the footings should be well below the depth that would be effected greatly by surface water.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are somewhere flat, since you refer to a sump that is (or would be) deep.

I can't imagine what sort of drain maintenance/replenishment you would do at any depth that would involve digging the drain up. If built correctly they should not need any maintenance.

In a non-flat area, I would always and have always chosen to run a drain line around the base of the footing, run out to daylight (no sump, gravity drainange to the surface at a lower point on the slope.) It costs practically nothing when the hole for the foundation is open, and stops ground water problems before they start. Yes, even on footings without a basement. However, that math might change if you do not have a complete trench excavated when placing the "individual footings" (*i.e.*, if you are more or less drilling holes for them.) In that case, you might as well skip it if you'd be incurring major expense to add it.

In a flat area you could do the same but run to a (probably exterior) sump/drywell - don't install a pump in the sump, just provide conduits and pipes to support installing a pump if one ever became advisable. You can monitor the water level (if any) in the sump.